# Firebase Hostingに独自ドメインを設定できない

Tags: firebase

お名前.comにて取得したドメインを設定しても「ドメインを追加できません。別のプロジェクトにすでに登録されている可能性があります。」と表示されます。

一度は成功したんですが、誤解からHostingのドメイン設定を削除しまい、もう一度設定したら下記のエラーが出てしまいました。 解決法はありますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

私も同じ現象が起きて調査した結果、以下の問題が2022/11/10(アメリカ時間)から発生していることがわかりました。
https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/Zp7duyfdPdixgNADEhHm
現時点では待つ以外の方法はないと思われます。

Comment: 私も困っています。
公式では既に解決しているということなのですが、こちらの操作ミスなのでしょうか？

Comment: sodaさん、こちらで個別に問い合わせるのが良いと思います。
私はこちらの問題は解決したのですが別の問題が発生して個別に問い合わせることにしました・・・
https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact